# c# - MySQL connector universal SELECT query method for mutliple tables

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to write a method that returns a list with every row that a select query returns. But anything I can find on this is based on a single table.

This is what I'm trying:

```
public List<string> Select(string querystring)
    {
        string query = "SELECT " + querystring;

        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        if (this.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                // in here I don't want a to "hard code" every column
                results.Add( "returned data" );
            }

            dataReader.Close();

            this.CloseConnection();

            return results;
        }
        else
        {
            return results;
        }
    }
```

Is this possible? Do I need to make a new method for every table?
Or should I maybe return a list of objects instead of strings?

I'm really having a brainfart here so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly... it looks like you're hoping to put a rows and columns (your data set) into just rows (your list of string).  How are you planning on using this data?  It will not be very useable trying to use it in the manner it looks like you're attempting.  You can reference your data readers columns by index, but again I'm not clear on what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: yes I know, but if i reference them by index for example for a table with 4 columns, the method won't work for a table with 5 columns, so the question is, how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As I stated from my comment:

> I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly... it looks like you're hoping to put a rows and columns (your data set) into just rows (your list of string). How are you planning on using this data? It will not be very useable trying to use it in the manner it looks like you're attempting. You can reference your data readers columns by index, but again I'm not clear on what you're hoping to accomplish.

You *can* however do it by doing something like this:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
    // for loop with a maximum iteration of the number of columns in the reader.
    for (int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
    { 
        results.Add(reader[i].ToString()); 
    } 
}
```

but again, I don't think this will get you data in a useable manner.

Comment: I will try this, I know i won't be able to do alot with this data but show it, But i do not need to do any math with the results, its just for showing purposes. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look into Dapper.NET or EF6 or nHibernate.